# .NET WebRequest Throttling

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, httpwebrequest

I'm using C# .NET 4 and MSSQL.

The code uses WebRequest to download the html of different websites.
The code is multi threaded.

I want to limit the number of requests per mintue for a pre-defined list of domains.

For example

**Domain: www.domain1.com Request Per Min : 5**

**Domain: www.domain2.com Request Per Min : 20**

i saw some questions/topics that recommended to implement a "leaky bucket". I'm just not sure how to do that.

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
while (true)
        {
            // read how long to wait between scans
            // we do this here so that we could, conceivably, update this value while the scanner is running
            int scanwaittime = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WaitTime"].ToString());


            if (Engine.IsRunning)
            {
                // engine is already running another scan - give it some more time
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(scanwaittime);
            }
            else
            {
                ...
            }
        }
```

This should point you in the right direction, I think.